# Drupal, Joomla and WordPress benchmark results

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla

So there is this benchmark at http://sven.webiny.com/benchmark-webiny-vs-wordpress-vs-drupal-vs-joomla-vs-tomatocms/ 
Can I really trust it? I mean it came as a surprise to me that Drupal is so much faster than Wordpress and Joomla. I always thought of it as a super heavy CPU devouring monster compared to the aforementioned.

Comment: Don't know if you can trust this benchmark, but drupal front is fast since it uses an efficient cache system

Answer (score 5):

That benchmark is like comparing a train with a plane. Yes, a plane is faster, but that doesn't mean that you should take a plane to commute to work.

A CMS is just a tool, and you need the tool that is most suitable for your project. There is a huge difference between a corporate brochure (5 pages, little interaction, no logged in users), a blog (100 pages, some interaction, some logged in users) and a community platform (10000 pages, lots of interaction, most users logged in). I think every CMS in that benchmark can be the top performer for a specific type of site.

Comment: In the latter category (10,000 pages, most users logged in) which CMSes would you consider? My contention is that Wordpress will hold up pretty well even in that scenario if the overall infrastructure is good enough -- page + query caching, CDN, etc.

Comment: SO is not really a place to discuss personal preferences, but that said: I would consider only Drupal for all 3 categories, simply because it's the tool I'm most skilled in.

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking stock installs of these three CMSes is useless. No one uses them without additional modules (which often have major performance implications), and anyone competent is going to set up performance enhancers like caching.

Do note, also, that the CMS that comes out on-top for every benchmark category is the blog author's own project.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress with a caching plugin would be just as fast.

Put NGINX in front of the webserver, and what CMS you use is immaterial. The site will be much faster.

Put your site's static assets on a CDN, and even better.

WP is easy to work with and expand. Drupal takes a gazillion modules and many queries per page. Both have excellent caching modules.

This is 2011. Not 1999. Frontend "performance" of a website to a visitor has very little to do with the backend. Movable Type would be the fastest of all of these because it writes out plain HTML files, but who wants to use the archaic CGI technology with limited plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I'm a big fan of Joomla. If you're new to CMS, Joomla has much 
less of a learning curve - and despite statements to the contrary - is just as 
capable as Drupal for running large/popular sites. But choosing a proper CMS 
depends on your experience level and the time you have to spend on the project. 
To know more about the differences among your mentioned CMSs refer to

[Comparison of Top 3 CMSs: WordPress vs Drupal vs Joomla](http://www.threehosts.com/ratings/comparison-software/wordpress-vs-joomla-vs-drupal.html). There you can get 
the detailed info in a simple format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Max!  Generally when supplying links in answers it is considered good form to provide a summary of the information contained therein.  In this particular case it would be great if you could say something about the comparison's benchmark results (if any).